# Scalability in MongoDB with thousands of queries

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, scalability, pymongo

I have a code that runs without an error, but it is really slow, due to the number of queries in a MongoDB.

I have a big python list (~5000 items) and I want to test when two of the items exist at the same time in a document in MongoDB.

```
mylist = ['apple','banana','melon','orange']
for i in mylist:
   for j in mylist[mylist.index(i):]:
       test = db.collection.find_one({'mylabel':{'$all':[i,j]}})
       if test:
          then do my stuff
```

where `mylabel` is also a list with items from `mylist`.

In a list of 150-200 items, it is a matter of a few minutes to finish. But in a list like mine  and even with more items, I will need several hours. Is there any way to improve it in base of time?

Edit upon request:

I haven't create an index. Here is an example of the structure in my database (however it is too simple)

```
{
 "_id": 1,
 "postid": 1,
 "mylabel":['apple','banana','melon']
}
{
 "_id": 2,
 "postid": 2,
 "mylabel":['banana','melon']
}
```

`_id` is the standard id from MongoDB, `postid` is a custom id I give to the document and `mylabel` is a list of labels.

Answer (score 1):

So after getting all the required information, here is my answer:

1. You need an index on the field `myLabel`. This is how you do it: `db.collection.ensureIndex({'myLabel': 1});` I am hoping this will speed up the queries. It is a standard technique.
2. Apart from that you can try to bring the entire collection in the memory. Or if your memory isn't enough, you can upgrade it for faster performance.
3. If your collection is very large, you can shard it. This will incorporate some parallelism in your query.

As far as the complexity of this code is concerned, you can't do better than O(n^2).

Comment: I have updated my question with the information you need. Thank you!

Comment: so what items are you querying?

Comment: I iterate through mylist and check for every possible couple of items, if they both exist in the same document in the field `mylabel` which is a list.

Comment: If possible, please mention how much speedup you could get after creating the index.

Comment: I haven't used timeit to measure the speedup. But I can see an small improvement. Maybe a reduce of 10 min per hour. I would like to test it again tomorrow with a timeit. Until then, if you have any other suggestions, let me know. At the moment, I upvote your answer and if I see an improvement in timeit too, then I will check it as the best answer.

Comment: i think there is possibility to improve it further after seeing the code a little bit more. would surely elaborate if i think of something else too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best thing to do with 5000 items in an array ( you could try ) but you could at least speed things up a bit provided you have a MongoDB 2.6 or greater version with some operators in the aggregation framework.

Just notating in JavaScript for simplicity, not that much different to the python code anyhow

```js
var mylist = ['apple','banana','melon','orange'];
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match possible documents excluding single element and empty
    // arrays that cannot possibly match
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            { "mylabel": { "$in": mylist } },
            { "mylabel": { "$not": { "$size": 1 } } }
        ]
    }},

    // Project the size of the set-intersection
    { "$project": {
        "postid": 1,
        "mylabel": 1,
        "size": { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$mylabel", "mylist" ] } }
    }},

    // Match only the documents with "size" greater than or equal to 2
    { "$match": { "size": { "$gte": 2 } }
])
```

Pretty self explanatory, match the documents that contain at least one of your match list items and that must have their own array size of 2 or greater in order to produce a probable match. Then the [**`$setIntersection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator comes in to compare the arrays and find the items that are the same. The resulting array is tested with [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/), which in this context is an aggregation operator to determine the size of the resulting array.

The final [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) filters out any results which did not report a "size" of 2 or more items matched. So those are the documents containing at least two of the items in your match list. That should really filter down the results, and is actually what you are asking for.

See if it works for you with 5000 elements in your match list, or otherwise try splitting up your match list. It shouldn't break the BSON limit, and though I don't think the comparison would be great in terms of performance, it still should not take hours.

Your biggest time problem in your current process is the need to fire of all of the queries for all the combinations of two. The point here is negate that network traffic and let the engine do the work.

Also there is a flaw in your `find_one` methodology in that there is undoubtedly more than one match for any paired combination. This means that your current process is likely to miss documents that actually match the conditions.

Also, do add an index to you array field. While the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) statement here is not going to filter everything by itself, it is probable that at least some of the documents in your collection can be filtered out and an index will help to avoid scanning every document in your collection.

Finally, the result is likely still a large number of documents so it would be advised to look at using a "cursor" as your output method rather than the default which is one big list. See the pymongo documentation on [aggregate](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) for the syntax and example.

---

If not on MongoDB 2.6 or greater than mapReduce is probably the safest option:

```js
var mylist = ['apple','banana','melon','orange'];
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {

        result = mylist.filter(function(n) {
            return this.mylist.indexOf(n) != -1
        });

        if ( result.length >= 2 )
            emit( this._id, this );

    },
    function(){},
    {
        "query": {
            "$and": [
                { "mylabel": { "$in": mylist } },
                { "mylabel": { "$not": { "$size": 1 } } }
            ]
        },
        "out": "outputcollection",
        "scope": { "mylist": mylist }
    }
)
```

Same thing, finds the documents that match a "set intersection" size of greater than 2. The arguments in "scope" and "query" will be just the python list which will serialize into the request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to test your method too, but I have an error `raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code) failed: exception: invalid operator '$size'`

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Your MongoDB server version is not 2.6.0 or 2.6.1. It is possible to do this through using `$unwind` on arrays, but if your comparison list truly is 5000 items then I would not recommend it. There might be a way to swing this with mapReduce. Performance will not be great but it would still be faster than what you are doing. By a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I check it now and I have 2.4.9. I have a small experience in mapReduce. Maybe I could give it a try.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Added a simple mapper ( no reduce required ) to do this with mapReduce.